# Sharepoint 2013 - How to programmatically clear (delete) single-value taxonomy (managed metadata) field

Tags: sharepoint-2013, taxonomy

I have an event listener that updates a list when an action occurs. The list has two taxonomy fields that need to be updated: 'State' and 'Product'

State is a multi-value field and Product is a single-value field. I can clear the 'State' field without issue, but get an error when trying to clear the 'Product' field. Below is the code:

```
Private Sub RemoveStateProduct(ctx As ClientContext, stateGuidToRemove As String, id As String)
    Dim listItems As ListItemCollection
    Dim queryXml As String = String.Empty
    Dim camlQueryForItem As New CamlQuery()

    ' get list item from item id
    Dim list As List = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("StateProductList")
    Dim fields As FieldCollection = list.Fields
    Dim statefield As Field = fields.GetByInternalNameOrTitle("States")
    Dim productfield As Field = fields.GetByInternalNameOrTitle("Product")

    queryXml = "<View>" & vbCr & vbLf & _
        "                                <Query>" & vbCr & vbLf & _
        "                                    <Where>" & vbCr & vbLf & _
        "                                        <Eq>" & vbCr & vbLf & _
        "                                            <FieldRef Name='ID'/>" & vbCr & vbLf & _
        "                                            <Value Type='Counter'>!@itemid</Value>" & vbCr & vbLf & _
        "                                        </Eq>" & vbCr & vbLf & _
        "                                    </Where>" & vbCr & vbLf & _
        "                                </Query>" & vbCr & vbLf & _
        "                            </View>"
    camlQueryForItem.ViewXml = queryXml.Replace("!@itemid", id)
    listItems = list.GetItems(camlQueryForItem)
    ctx.Load(listItems)
    ctx.Load(fields)
    ctx.Load(statefield)
    ctx.Load(productfield)
    ctx.ExecuteQuery()

    Dim stateTaxFieldAs TaxonomyField = ctx.CastTo(Of TaxonomyField)(statefield)
    Dim productTaxFieldAs TaxonomyField = ctx.CastTo(Of TaxonomyField)(productfield)
    Dim item As ListItem = listItems(0)

    Dim productTaxFieldValue As TaxonomyFieldValue = Nothing
    Dim stateTaxFieldValueCollAs TaxonomyFieldValueCollection = Nothing
    Dim stateTermValueString As String = String.Empty
    Dim tempString As String = String.Empty


    stateTaxFieldValueColl= TryCast(item("State"), TaxonomyFieldValueCollection)
    For Each tv As TaxonomyFieldValue In taxfieldvaluecollState
        tempString = tv.WssId & ";#" & tv.Label & "|" & tv.TermGuid
        If Not stateGuidToRemove.Equals(tv.TermGuid) Then
            stateTermValueString = stateTermValueString & tempString & ";#"
        End If
    Next

    stateTermValueString = stateTermValueString.TrimEnd("#", ";")
    stateTaxFieldValueColl= New TaxonomyFieldValueCollection(ctx, stateTermValueString, taxfieldState)
    taxfieldState.SetFieldValueByValueCollection(item, taxfieldvaluecollState)

    If stateTermValueString = String.Empty Then
        productTaxFieldValue = TryCast(item("Product"), TaxonomyFieldValue)
        'productTaxFieldValue = New TaxonomyFieldValue()
        productTaxFieldValue.WssId = 0 '-1
        productTaxFieldValue.Label = Nothing 'String.empty() ; vbNull
        productTaxFieldValue.TermGuid = Nothing 'String.empty() ; vbNull
        taxfieldProduct.SetFieldValueByValue(item, productTaxFieldValue)
    End If

    item.Update()
    ctx.Load(item)
    ctx.ExecuteQuery()

End Sub
```

The error occurs inside this last section:

```
    If stateTermValueString = String.Empty Then
        productTaxFieldValue = TryCast(item("Product"), TaxonomyFieldValue)
        'productTaxFieldValue = New TaxonomyFieldValue()
        productTaxFieldValue.WssId = 0 '-1
        productTaxFieldValue.Label = Nothing 'String.empty() ; vbNull
        productTaxFieldValue.TermGuid = Nothing 'String.empty() ; vbNull
        taxfieldProduct.SetFieldValueByValue(item, productTaxFieldValue)
    End If
```

If stateTermValueString is empty, I know that I must clear out the 'Product' field. I have tried creating a new TaxonomyFieldValue object and setting the values to Nothing (suggested by [this](http://blog.techperspect.com/2011/03/clearing-taxonomy-managed-metadata.html) article, though that is for 2010). I have also tried using the item's 'Product' field and resetting the values for that to make it empty. I have tried different combinations of values for the WssId, Label, and Guid fields, as shown in the commented sections of those lines. The code returns an error:

creatingField

That's it. That is the entire text of the error message I receive. When I examine the source, it is only this: Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime

So, the question: How do I programmatically clear a single-value taxonomy field?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. For a single-value taxonomy field, you must also update the hidden note field, but you cannot do it through a TaxonomyFieldValue object. You must update the item field directly using an array, and the note field with a string.

After loading the Taxonomy fields and item, you must reload the item fields and execute the query, then use the context to load the hidden note field.

```
Dim stateTaxField As TaxonomyField = ctx.CastTo(Of TaxonomyField)(statefield)
Dim productTaxField As TaxonomyField = ctx.CastTo(Of TaxonomyField)(productfield)
Dim item As ListItem = listItems(0)

'Add these lines
ctx.Load(stateTaxField)
ctx.Load(productTaxField)
ctx.Load(ctx.Web.Fields, Function(ff) ff.Include(Function(f) f.Id, Function(f) f.InternalName))
ctx.ExecuteQuery()
Dim productNoteField As Field = ctx.Web.Fields.ToList.SingleOrDefault(Function(f) f.Id.Equals(productTaxField.TextField))
```

I modified the section at the end that was causing so much trouble to update the item fields with empty values:

```
If termValueString = String.Empty Then
    item(productfield.InternalName) = String.Format("-1;#{0}|{1}", String.Empty, Guid.Empty).ToArray
    item(productNoteField.InternalName) = String.Format("{0}|{1}", String.Empty, Guid.Empty)
End If
```

*productTaxFieldValue* is not longer used and can be removed. [This article](http://chrisdomino.com/Blog/Post/Thoughts-On-Programming-Managed-Metadata-With-SharePoint-2013-s-CSOM-Taxonomy-API) was most helpful is determining how to format the field strings (and explaining that the productfield needed to be an array, even if is is only a single, 'empty' string). Hope this helps someone else in need.